# How to use relational database with flutter

Tags: sql, database, flutter

I'm currently making an app using Flutter. Now I really want the database to be SQL based and not NoSql like Firebase. What could be the possible options going about that? You can consider the application to be something like a social network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want to save data locally on your device then you can use sqflite plugin
2. And for like social media application you need to access data over the internet, in this case you have to build backend system and access data throw APi, for building backend system and APi you can chose multiple options

   1. PHP (using Laravel framework and relational database)
   2. JAVA (using Spring boot framework and relational database)
   3. PYTHON (Django framework and relational database)

and many more...

Comment: including Dart itself, using shelf or angel or aqueduct.